# Capacitor not charging

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor

I am basically a computer engineer but because of a robotics project I am in a need of designing a small UPS for a few seconds of backup (approximately 8-10 seconds), but I am facing the following problems:

1. The capacitor is not charging to 5 V even when connected to a power bank without using any resistor and without any load at the output.
2. Is a resistor always needed if we want to use a capacitor?
3. Is a load always needed and will a capacitor only then start conducting?

[image]

Comment: 1) Find (by reading its spec) the current your supply (V1) can provide. (if V1 is a power bank, remember your capacitor can't negotiate over USB! )  2) Use Ohm's Law to calculate R1 to provide that current from 5V. 3) Calculate the RC time constant ( R1 * C1) 4) Charge C1 for 5x that time constant. 5) measure voltage across C.

Comment: How are you determining the Supercap is not charging up?

Comment: @StarCat I am determining it with checking the voltage across the super capacitor terminals while the circuit is connected using multimeter

Comment: @Brian I didn’t get your point number 4. Can’t I keep the circuit as it is above and keep it on forever? I am going to use raspberry to output of above circuit. Does super capacitor just keeps sucking current and keep storing it even if it’s tummy is full to it’s capacity?

Comment: Is your supercapacitor rated for five volts? Many can't handle that much voltage, and would be destroyed by it.

Comment: I should have said 5*RC was a minimum time, permanent connection is fine, the C practically stops consuming current when fully charged (it will have a very small "leakage current", see its datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

1. Powerbanks are not meant to be connected to charge large capacitors. If the capacitor is empty, it will draw as much current as it can, more than what the powerbank can deliver, and the powerbank may protect itself from the overcurrent by turning the output off.
2. Not necessarily, but in this case it will help to limit the current to what the powerbank can deliver.
3. No, a load is not needed to charge the capacitor.

Comment: Sir kindly note my power bank and my super capacitor both are 5 volt ratings and my super capacitor is just 1 farad. Where the mistake is then? Please help.

Comment: I already explained that the capacitor connected to powerbank will try to take more current than the powerbank allows so it will not work.

Comment: My power bank allowed the current rating is 2.5 amperes at 5 volt. So can i use limiting current to 2.5 amp = 5 volt / 2 Ohm resistor ? So that power bank will not turn off itself as we have limited the current drawing from it to its ratings?

Comment: You can try that.